# rich text and tables

Tags: xpages

I've got a database in which people can create and edit documents with the notes client and with the web browser. Everything works fine as long as it comes to rich text and tables. Tables created and edited in the web (with the ckeditor) look crappy in the Notes Client. As far as I found out it's because the rich text field is being changed to a mime field. Changing the field properties in the form to store its content as HTML didn't help. Are there any ways to display a table in the notes client nearly as it looks like in the xpage? As I'm not able to distribute the extension library to all the clients I need to do this without xpinc and without displaying the form as Xpage.

This is what the table looks in the web and in the client:

web: http://y73i.img-up.net/web1dfd0.png

client http://n68i.img-up.net/client1ecc0.png

Answer (score 1):

The HTML -> RichtText -> HTML conversion is a challenge in Notes. The options you have are:

- XPiNC (if you look hard, it isn't too hard to deploy the extension library (using an update site and a policy)
- Coex Edit (Commercial product from [Geniisoft](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/CoexEdit)
- A composite app with an embedded browser (you can teach a composite app to open a page instead a form
- A embedded browser control in a Notes form

In any case you want to stick to HTML/MIME since that the the more neutral format.

Comment: thank you very much. using the embedded browser control works great

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer and blog about your solution. I'm sure there are more people interested

Comment: Do you have Mac or Linux users?